# Combined probability for drop chances in video games

Tags: probability, statistics, percentages

I don't really know how to describe my problem in maths terms, so maybe I try to describe what I like to calculate:

In video games, there are drop chances. When you kill a boss, there is an N% chance for a specific item to drop.

E.G:

**Item A** drops with a chance of **1%**
**Item B** drops with a chance of **5%**
**Item C** drops with a chance of **10%**

I already found out how to calculate the chance for an item to drop after N amount of tries.

E.G:

**Item A** (1% drop chance) has a **63.4%** chance of dropping at least once after **100 tries**.
**Item B** (5% drop chance) has a **40.13%** chance of dropping at least once after **10 tries**.
**Item C** (10% drop chance) has a **87.84%** chance of dropping at least once after **20 tries**.

But now I'd like to know how likely it is combined for all those tries. In other words:

> How likely is it, that after 100 tries at 1%, 10 tries at 5% and 20 tries at 10%, **no** item dropped yet?

Also, to add a bit more complexity. Is there a way to tell the luckiness or unluckiness when some items dropped, but some didn't yet.

E.G:

> How lucky or unlucky (in percent) is it, when: Item A dropped after 100 tries (63.4%), item B didn't drop yet after 10 tries (40.13%), and item C dropped after 20 tries (87.84%).

Is there any way to calculate a meaningful likeliness that can tell if I am X% lucky or unlucky?

Comment: How did you calculate the chance for an item to drop after N amount of tries?

Comment: @Mailbox This is what I came up with in JavaScript: https://gist.github.com/StephanWagner/0e5f1173749365df9cf996d3ab82a99e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming the drop probabilities of items A, B, and C are independent**, you have a 1-0.01=0.99 chance of not getting item A, and similarly 0.95 chance of not getting item B and 0.90 chance of not getting item C, on any given try.

Then, you can simply raise these to the relevant powers.

> How likely is it, that after 100 tries at 1%, 10 tries at 5% and 20 tries at 10%, no item dropped yet?

For this question, the answer is $0.99^{100} \cdot 0.95^{10} 0.90^{20}$.

As far as I know, your notion of "luckiness" or "unluckiness" doesn't seem to be too clear, but I think the best way to look at it would probably be looking at where the number of tries falls on the binomial distribution.